# Manually set headmark in scrheadings

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script

I am trying to get the proper header mark for my Preamble in my thesis.

```
\documentclass[headsepline,12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{section}
\lohead[\textbf{\headmark}]{\headmark}

\begin{document}

...


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\clearpage

\clearpage
\chapter*{Preamble}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preamble}
...
```

Now my problem is that on the page with the Preamble, it says "List of Tables" in the header. How do I change this (to e.g. "Preamble") without affecting the rest of the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you tell LaTeX to put the current section into the head (`\automark[section]{section}`), then LaTeX does not care about changing chapters.

What about this:

```
\documentclass[headsepline,12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\lohead[\textbf{\headmark}]{\headmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{first}
\label{cha:first}

\section{firstsection}
\label{sec:firstsection}


%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\clearpage

\clearpage
\addchap{Preamble}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preamble}

\section{YES!}
\label{sec:yes}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You commented out the manual toc entry for the lof, but never set option `listof`. Did you do that on purpose or forgot the option? :-)

Comment: Note that the optional argument of `\automark` will be ignored in an one sided document except you have set the option `autooneside=false`. `\lohead` is in an one sided document the same as `\ihead`. And I think `\clearpairofpagestyles` or `\chead[]{}\cfoot[]{}` should be added.